# Using "clusteringIdentifier" causes app to crash

Tags: swift, mapkit

I use MapKit in my application and places a lot of annotations. I want to dequeue the unnecessary annotations, to make sure that my RAM usage does not run amok. 
However, with my current code the application, will crash when trying to zoom back out. To me, it seems like the crash happens when I try to "re-cluster" my annotations.

I have tried to implement the map without using "dequeueReusableAnnotationView", which works as intended. However, the more you browse the map, the more RAM it will use and at a certain point it will become sluggish.

This is the code from the delegate that I actually got working. However, this does not implement dequeuing, so it's not a feasible solution:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        //Keep it default for the user location
        if mapView.userLocation.isEqual(annotation) {
            return nil;
        }

        let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView()
        annotationView.isEnabled = true
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView?.markerTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1)
        annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = identifier
        annotationView.glyphImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PLACEHOLDER-glyph-icon")
        annotationView.titleVisibility = .hidden
        annotationView.subtitleVisibility = .hidden
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)

        return annotationView
    }
}
```

This is my "HouseMarker.swift" class:

```
import MapKit

class HouseMarker: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(title: String, subtitle: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

This is my delegate function, which causes my crash on "zoom out"-pinching:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        //Keep it default for the user location
        if mapView.userLocation.isEqual(annotation) {
            return nil;
        }

        let identifier = "HouseMarker"

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
            annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            annotationView?.markerTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1)
            annotationView?.clusteringIdentifier = identifier
            annotationView?.glyphImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PLACEHOLDER-glyph-icon")
            annotationView?.titleVisibility = .hidden
            annotationView?.subtitleVisibility = .hidden
        } else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        return annotationView
    }
}
```

When I pinch to zoom out, the application freezes and this is the error I am getting:

```
2019-08-25 21:04:26.646836+0200 housing[474:160023] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[housing.HouseMarker memberAnnotations]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28261dc70'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ad272ab8 0x1ac477d00 0x1ad18b108 0x1ad278464 0x1ad27a260 0x1bdf46cb8 0x1be0b92f4 0x1ad157124 0x1bdf27424 0x1be0b9efc 0x1bdf3354c 0x1bdf24094 0x1bdf23490 0x1bdf23870 0x1bd90c0fc 0x1bdf24d74 0x1bdf24f58 0x1da2a9668 0x1da2b1b28 0x1da2af424 0x1da2ae8f8 0x1da2a26bc 0x1da2a1de8 0x1da2a1bb8 0x1da6d4f44 0x1da6b41e8 0x1da77f3e8 0x1da781ba4 0x1ad202b54 0x1ad202ad0 0x1ad20238c 0x1ad1fd060 0x1ad1fc964 0x1af43dd8c 0x1da699758 0x100514470 0x1accb8fd8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate method is not handling every possibility. After

```
    if mapView.userLocation.isEqual(annotation) {
        return nil;
    }
```

Do the same thing for a clustering annotation:

```
    if annotation is MKClusterAnnotation {
        return nil
    }
```

Also note that in modern iOS you are dequeuing wrong. You should register your annotation with the map view and so your dequeued annotation view will never be nil.